# Services with ES6 (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, ecmascript-6, angular-services

I'm having problems accessing Angular built-in services such as $http when creating a service with ES6.

For example, I'm creating a "ResultsFinder" service that will do an AJAX call and then do some stuff. 
The problem is that I only have access to $http on the constructor (if I pass it as an argument), but not on other methods (such as getResults).

See this code example:

```js
(() => {
  'use strict';

  class ResultsFinder {
    constructor($http) {}
    getResults() {
      return 'ResultsFinder';
    }
  }

  /**
   * @ngdoc service
   * @name itemManager.service:ResultsFinder
   *
   * @description
   *
   */
  angular
    .module('itemManager')
    .service('ResultsFinder', ResultsFinder);
}());
```

Inside getResults I don't have access to $http. In order to have access I should do something that I don't feel right like this:

```js
(() => {
  'use strict';

  class ResultsFinder {
    constructor($http) {
      this.$http = $http;
    }
    getResults() {
      // Here I have access to this.$http
      return 'ResultsFinder';
    }
  }

  /**
   * @ngdoc service
   * @name itemManager.service:ResultsFinder
   *
   * @description
   *
   */
  angular
    .module('itemManager')
    .service('ResultsFinder', ResultsFinder);
}());
```

Anyone can give me some advice about the proper way to handle this?

Comment: This is how class works, you have to define your properties in the constructor and access them in other methods. There is nothing wrong doing that.

Comment: Then it's the propper way to create services? I find weird having to access "global" services with this.$service.

Comment: The service is not global. It is a member of the class. In browsers global vars are properties of `window`. `window.$http.get("/")` would be invalid. With TypeScript you would be able to annotate the member as `private`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `this.$http` inside your `getResults` method.

```js
(() => {
  'use strict';
      
class ResultsFinder {
 
    static $inject = ['$http'];   
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }
  
    getResults() {
        return this.$http.get('/foo/bar/');
    }
}

  /**
   * @ngdoc service
   * @name itemManager.service:ResultsFinder
   *
   * @description
   *
   */
  angular
    .module('itemManager')
    .service('ResultsFinder', ResultsFinder);
}());
```

As a side note, I added a static `$inject` "annotation" to your class. This is a best practice if you are not using something like ngAnnotate. It also makes it easier to change out implementations by only changing the `$inject` values.

If you are a ES5 developer it may help to think about how this would look in ES5

```
ResultsFinder.$inject = ['$http'];
var ResultsFinder = function($http) {
    this.$http = $http;
}

ResultsFinder.prototype.getResults = function() {
    return this.$http.get('/foo/bar/');
}
```

**NOTE**

Since you are using ES6, should probably use ES6 modules to organize your code.

You define and export your angular-module within an ES6 module:

```
import {module} from 'angular';

export var itemManager = module('itemManager', []);
```

Then import the Angular module

```
import {itemManager} from '../itemManager';

class ResultsFinder {

    static $inject = ['$http'];   
    constructor($http) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    getResults() {
        return this.$http.get('/foo/bar/');
    }
}

itemManager.service('ResultFinder', ResultFinder);
```

Comment: When your code is `uglified` or `minified` the function parameter `$http` will be replaces with something like: `a`. Angular will not know what service to inject at this point. That is where `$inject` comes in. This is typically only an issue that is seen once code is shipped to QA or PROD.

Comment: You should use `$http` rather than `http`.

Comment: Yes, in your controller you would want `MyController.$inject = ['ResultsFinder'];`.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem like good practice, to me. I agree with the OP's hesitation to use `this.$http` because then that just becomes cruft outside of the service. Someone could then use `ResultsFinder.$http` - I agree, this doesn't feel right. Any other solutions?

Comment: Jordan -- You would only be able to do ResultsFinder.$http if during build you DON'T wrap your module in an IIFE. This should always be done. Or, just wrap the class in a IIFE. Doing encapsulation within the constructor will give you a performance hit.